# Recursive function in C returning only once a pointer or NULL

Tags: c, recursion

SO i am trying to write a recursive function, in which i only want to have "one" return.

So what I am trying to do is, first I have defined a simple recursive structure:

```
typedef struct CHAP CHAP;

struct CHAP{

 int ID;
 CHAP** list;
 int nb;

};
```

Now in my function I want to find and return a pointer to CHAP if it has the same ID as my target. So far I have this:

```
CHAP* find_chap(CHAP* ch, CHAP* target){

     if (ch->ID == target->ID) return ch;

     for (int i=0; i<ch->nb; i++){
         find_chap(ch->list[i], target);
     }
    //return NULL?
 }
```

However I am not sure how to return something if the entry is not found? So in that case I would like to return NULL but I don't know where exactly to place it. I am not considering the case if the ID is contained at several entries, then only the first found pointer will be returned.

If I do it in the line where it is commented out, the function and recursion calls will continue even after a entry is found, which is not what i want :/

Comment: Should you not check what the recursive call to `find_chap` return?

Comment: Returning `NULL` if no entry iks found seems appropriate here. BTW you don't need recursion here.

Comment: You must use `return find_chap(...);`

Comment: Well I need a recursion because the entries of the ->list can also then have again an allocated ->list and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to:

- Record whether the current parameter `ch` matches your target
- Loop over the `ch` child nodes  until either you have a match to return (which you may already) or exhaust the list.
- Return the result of the above.

In short, something like this:

```
CHAP* find_chap(CHAP* ch, CHAP* target)
{
    CHAP *res = (ch->ID == target->ID) ? ch : NULL;

    for (int i=0; !res && i<ch->nb; ++i)
        res = find_chap(ch->list[i], target);

    return res;
}
```

That should fulfill your requirement of having a single `return` point in the function, while still recursing children.

Comment: Can you tell me what the `!res` in the loop is standing for. I have seen this notation before but i could not find anywhere an explanation. I am confused because res is a pointer and not a bool or integer value

Comment: @malajedala that's the test for whether `res` is still NULL or not. It is equivalent to `(res == NULL)`. The loop will break as soon as (a) `res` is non-NULL, or (b) `i` has met `ch->nb`. Note that if `res` was already set to non-NULL on the first line because `ch->ID == target->ID`, then the loop effectively becomes a noop and no iterations take place; `!res` becomes *false* and therefore the for-condition is no longer meetable.

Comment: Oh I see. I just tried your example and it is exactly what I was trying to do. Thank you so much for your help and your explanations!

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to return a value from the recursive call:

```
CHAP* find_chap(CHAP* ch, CHAP* target){

     if (ch->ID == target->ID) return ch;

     for (int i=0; i<ch->nb; i++){
         CHAP * c = find_chap(ch->list[i], target);
         if (c != NULL) return c;         // return not null value if one was found
     }
    return NULL;   // not found here...
 }
```